# switch文の中でのステータス表示を繰り返したい

Tags: java

現在、javaでキャラクター育成ゲームの作成を行っています。コンパイルして

1. ミルクを与える
2. 寝る
3. あやす

という選択肢を入力して、switchでその選択肢ごとにポイントが加算されるよう分岐させています。
それぞれ選択No.を入力した段階で、その度にポイント加算されたステータスが表示されるようにしたいのですが（getYutoStatus()関数が表示）、現在は

```
$ java part01
Yuto君、こんにちは！！
Yuto君は今0才です
頑張って育てよう
1. ミルクを与える
2. 寝る
3. あやす
2
1. ミルクを与える
2. 寝る
3. あやす
3
1. ミルクを与える
2. 寝る
3. あやす
4
Yuto君は育成ポイント17でマイナスポイント0
Yuto君は育成ポイント17でマイナスポイント0
```

のようにそのまま次の選択の処理に入ってしまい、結果は最期に表示されています。
その都度「入力＋結果表示」にする様にできる記述の方法を教えて欲しいです。
よろしくお願いします。

```
public class part01{
    static String name = "Yuto"; //キャラクターの名前
    static int age;          //キャラクターの年齢
    static int good = 5;         //キャラクターの育成ポイント
    static int wagamama = 0;     //キャラクターのマイナスポイント

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
        putOpening();
        putCommand();
        putStageClear();
    }

    public static void putCommand() throws java.io.IOException{

        put("1. ミルクを与える");
        put("2. 寝る");
        put("3. あやす");

        switch(inputCommand()){
            case '1':{
                good += 2;
                putCommand();
                getYutoStatus();
                break;
            }
            case '2':{
                good += 5;
                putCommand();
                getYutoStatus();
                break;
            }
            case '3':{
                good += 7;
                putCommand();
                getYutoStatus();
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    /**
    * オープニングを表示
    */
    public static void putOpening(){
        System.out.println(name + "君、こんにちは！！");
        System.out.println(name + "君は今" + age + "才です");
        System.out.println("頑張って育てよう");
    }

    public static void getYutoStatus(){
        put(name + "君は" + "育成ポイント" + good + "で" + "マイナスポイント" + wagamama);
    }

    /**
    * ステージクリア画面を表示
    */
    public static void putStageClear(){

        if(good >= 20){
            age = 1;
            put(name + "君は" + age + "才になりました!!");
        }else if(good >= 30){
            age = 2;
            put(name + "君は" + age + "才になりました!!");
        }else if(good >= 40){
            age = 3;
            put(name + "君は" + age + "才になりました!!");
        }
    }

    /**
    * 育児を行う
    */
    /*
    static void ikuji(){
    //育児ポイントの上昇
    //わがまま・マイナスポイント
        int d = r.nextInt(8);
        wagamama　-= d;

    }
    */

    public static int inputCommand() throws java.io.IOException{

            int c = System.in.read();
            if(c == 10 || c == 13){
                return(inputCommand());
            }
            return(c);
    }

    public static void put(String str){
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

Comment: putCommandメソッドにあるputCommand() と getYutoStatus();を逆にするだけで解決しませんか？

Comment: putCommandが再帰呼び出しになっているように見えますが、意図した記述でしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

結論からいわせていただきますと、switch文の中のgetYutoStatus()をputCommand()の前にすればいいと思います。

補足：
1. switch文にdefault処理をいれましょう
2. nameをprivate static finalにしましょう
3. inputCommandメソッドのif文のところ、マジックナンバーように見えますが、10と13って何でしょうか？意味のある数字であれば、定数を定義して使ってみませんか